# Empty string in language closed under concatenation

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

Does a regular language L that is closed under concatenation necessarily contain the empty string?

Comment: How about the language admitting words $a^n$ ($n\in\mathbb Z^+$), i.e. $a, aa, aaa, aaaa, \ldots$ but not $\varepsilon$?

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! I was unsure whether the words "closed under concatenation" required that the empty string belong to the language.

Comment: I cannot vouch for every author/book in the world, but for me it means - if you concatenate a string of $\ge 1$ $a$'s to another string of $\ge 1$ $a$'s, you will get a new string of $\ge 1$ (and actually of $\ge 2$) $a$'s.

Comment: Doesn't a regular language have to be closed under the Kleene star operation, and thus, by the definition of that operation, require ε to be part of the alphabet?

Comment: @Alexis No, a regular language does not have to be closed under star.

Comment: @j-e-pin: Ah okay, thank you .... So is [the 'closure properties' section of the Wikipedia entry on 'regular language'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties) incorrect, or am I simply misunderstanding what it's saying?

Answer (score 1):

Take any language $L$ of $A^*$. Then $L^+$, which is by definition the subsemigroup of $A^*$ generated by $L$, is closed under concatenation.